# rvm: how do I really know it works

Tags: jruby, rvm

I installed rvm successfully and then installed ruby 1.8.7, ruby 1.9.2, and jruby 1.6.0.  I currently use 1.8.7 for all of my rails projects, but I would like to experiment with 1.9.2, and I would also like to deploy jruby on those environments which are Java-specific.

So, I used rvm to select jruby and then I ran my current rails app on mongrel @ localhost:3000.  It worked great.  Then, I ran a Linux process command and looked at the names of the processes running and I found ruby1.8.  Does that mean that the Mongrel instance loaded ruby 1.8, but rails is using jruby-1.6.0?  I don't know.  Who can tell me how to determine that I really am running jruby?

Answer (score 0):

```
type rvm | head -1
```

The above line should say that RVM is a function and confirms it was installed correctly.

Did you have trouble with instructions on entering the line

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

into your bash profile? That was a little unclear in my opinion. If it's that, you need to go to your home directory and make a .bash_profile (source: http://donovan.covblogs.com/archives/027838.html)

The above needs to be done before you can rly ensure ruby 1.9.2 is installed, else it'll be forgotten/lost once you close your shell.

Regarding the version of ruby you're using, make sure you're setting the default version. Below was taken from the Ruby on Rails 3 tutorial so feel free to change some naming conventions:

```
$ rvm --create 1.8.7-p174@rails2tutorial
$ rvm --create use 1.9.2@rails3tutorial
```

then

```
$ rvm --default use 1.9.2@rails3tutorial
```

Finall, type `$ ruby -v` and you should get `ruby 1.9.2`

Source: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#sec:install_ruby

Answer (score 0):

I found this very helpful after starting to use rvm:  i added this to the end of my .bashrc file:  it puts the currently selected rvm and gemset at the start of the command prompt, in red:  most of the following script is taken up with defining colors - you could delete the ones you don't need once you choose the colors you want.

```
##################################################
### RVM-specific command line (PS1): show current rvm and gemset

function __my_rvm_ruby_version {
  local gemset=$(echo $GEM_HOME | awk -F'@' '{print $2}')
  [ "$gemset" != "" ] && gemset="@$gemset"
  local version=$(echo $MY_RUBY_HOME | awk -F'-' '{print $2}')
  local full="$version$gemset"
  [ "$full" != "" ] && echo "$full "
}

bash_prompt() {
  local NONE="\[\033[0m\]"    # unsets color to term's fg color

  # regular colors
  local K="\[\033[0;30m\]"    # black
  local R="\[\033[0;31m\]"    # red
  local G="\[\033[0;32m\]"    # green
  local Y="\[\033[0;33m\]"    # yellow
  local B="\[\033[0;34m\]"    # blue
  local M="\[\033[0;35m\]"    # magenta
  local C="\[\033[0;36m\]"    # cyan
  local W="\[\033[0;37m\]"    # white

  # emphasized (bolded) colors
  local EMK="\[\033[1;30m\]"
  local EMR="\[\033[1;31m\]"
  local EMG="\[\033[1;32m\]"
  local EMY="\[\033[1;33m\]"
  local EMB="\[\033[1;34m\]"
  local EMM="\[\033[1;35m\]"
  local EMC="\[\033[1;36m\]"
  local EMW="\[\033[1;37m\]"

  # background colors
  local BGK="\[\033[40m\]"
  local BGR="\[\033[41m\]"
  local BGG="\[\033[42m\]"
  local BGY="\[\033[43m\]"
  local BGB="\[\033[44m\]"
  local BGM="\[\033[45m\]"
  local BGC="\[\033[46m\]"
  local BGW="\[\033[47m\]"
  local UC=$W                 # user's color
  [ $UID -eq "0" ] && UC=$R   # root's color

  PS1="$R\$(__my_rvm_ruby_version)$Y\h$W:$EMY\W${NONE}$ "  
}

bash_prompt
unset bash_prompt
############## PS1 editing section ends
```